# How to start using KtimeTracker?

Tags: time, calendar, tracker

I installed ktimetracker from Sofware Center. When I run it trough launcher o writing "ktimetracker" in console. It ask me for a iCalendar file (I think so), I've never heard of that type of file, so, I create a empty file with the extension .ics (I think this is the extension of iCalendar files) and I specified ktimetracker that use that file, but it doesn't work. Some one knows what I have to do to get ktimetracker work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**KtimeTracker**

```
:~$ apt-cache show ktimetracker
```

> Description: time tracker tool  KTimetracker is a time tracker for
>   busy people who need to keep track  of the amount of time they spend
>   on various tasks.  .  This package is part of the KDE PIM module.
>   Homepage: http://pim.kde.org/

**KDE-PIM & KDE & Kubuntu**

http://userbase.kde.org/Kde-pim

http://www.kde.org/

http://www.kubuntu.org/

**The KTimetracker manual from the KDE UserBase**

http://userbase.kde.org/KTimeTracker

**The KTimetracker Handbook**

http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kdepim/ktimetracker/

Comment: I read the manual before asking, but I still don't understand

Comment: Is Ktimetracker still available? I have Kubuntu 17.04 with PIM 12.16.3

Comment: By https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=279784 the ktimetracker has been dropped.